# How to make regular expression that matches tokens within multiline strings?

Tags: java, regex

I am reading a properties file like this in Java:

```
@name=single line value
@description=multiline value
...
user@server.com

@key=single line value
```

I want to match every key/value pair. All keys are prefixed with the '@' character, and multiline values are allowed. I am using this regex (global, multiline): **`^@[^@]+=.+\n*[^@]*`**. Please, see http://regexr.com/39p9b for details and testing.

The problem is I am leaving out values with '@' in the middle, like e-mail addresses. So how can I fix the regex?

Comment: `user@server.com`should be in `@description`value?

Comment: @jhamon yes, that's right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the following one:

```
^@[^=]+=(?:[^@]|(?<!^)@)+$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/20w-jUB5jgt_BRJa)

Don't forget the [multiline flag](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE).